# Additional values populated in Column next to where results are correctly provided

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

The code below works as expected with lowest rate using the 3 criteria in columns A,B & C and finding the lowest value from Column D. The results are added in each row in Column E. But for some reason I am getting duplicated and wrong results added to Column F and I can't figure out why?

```
Sub FindLowestValuewith3criteria()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim dict As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim key As String
Dim minValue As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orbit") ' Replace "Sheet1" with the actual sheet name
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws.Range("A2:D" & lastRow) ' Assuming headers are in row 1
rng.Value = ws.Range("A2:D" & lastRow).Value


Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each cell In rng
    key = cell.Value & "_" & cell.OffSet(0, 1).Value & "_" & cell.OffSet(0, 2).Value ' Combine three criteria values as the dictionary key
    
    If Not dict.exists(key) Then ' Check if the key already exists in the dictionary
        dict.Add key, cell(1, 4) ' If not, add the value from Column D as the initial value
    Else
        minValue = dict(key) ' Get the current minimum value for the key
        If cell(1, 4) < minValue Then ' Compare the current value with the minimum value
            dict(key) = cell(1, 4) ' Update the minimum value if the current value is lower
        End If
    End If
Next cell

' Output the minimum values in Column E
ws.Range("E2:E" & lastRow).ClearContents ' Clear previous results
For Each cell In rng
    key = cell(1, 1) & "_" & cell(1, 2) & "_" & cell(1, 3)
    cell(1, 5) = dict(key) ' Output the minimum value in Column E
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each cell In rng` will loop over A2, B2, C2, D2 then A3, B3, etc.   Maybe you wanted `For Each cell In rng.Columns(1).Cells` ?

Comment: thanks ! That solved the error entries in Column F. By debugging step by step I realized the code will start with a Key built from the three columns but on the next cycle it will then change the key to built from two columns. I only want the lowest if all three criteria are used. How would I fix that ?

Comment: See my suggestion below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this all in one array (and it will be faster)

```vb
Sub FindLowestValuewith3criteria()

    Dim r As Long, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim key As String, arr, v
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orbit") ' Replace "Sheet1" with the actual sheet name
    
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:E" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)
    arr = rng.Value 'read all values into a 2D array, including col E
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        key = Join(Array(arr(r, 1), arr(r, 2), arr(r, 3)), "_")
        v = arr(r, 4)
        If Not dict.exists(key) Then
            dict.Add key, v
        Else
            If v < dict(key) Then dict(key) = v
        End If
    Next r
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        key = Join(Array(arr(r, 1), arr(r, 2), arr(r, 3)), "_")
        arr(r, 5) = dict(key)
    Next r
    
    rng.Value = arr  'put the array back on the sheet
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I added this line to skip to next item in loop in case the Key does not have a value.              If v = 0 Then GoTo Skip
        If Not dict.exists(key) Then
            dict.Add key, v
        Else
            If v < dict(key) Then dict(key) = v
        End If
Skip:
    Next r